# Spring Boot Gradle Build : A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

Recently I have update my spring boot app from 1.5.6.Release to 2.3.5. While building project I am facing following problem :

> Description:
>
> A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could
> not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
> configuration.

Following is my code:(@Repository and EnableJpaRepositories annotation are not required in spring boot)

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    @ServletComponentScan
    public class Application {
    
      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        for (String arg : args) {
          
        }
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
    }
    
    
    
    public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    
    }
    
    @RestController
    public class PersonController {
    
      private final EntityRepository entities;
    
      @Autowired
      public PersonController(EntityRepository wntities) {
        this.etities = entities;
      }
    
    ….
    …..
    
    }
```

```
> WARN 79448 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext :
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'EntityRepository' defined in
> com.abc.EntityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> create inner bean '(inner bean)#6010d0d1' of type
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
> bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6010d0d1': Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
> argument; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
>       INFO 79448 --- [main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'


Description:

A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Gradle Build file :

```
buildscript {
            ext {
                springBootVersion = ‘2.3.5’
            }
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://artifactory.domain.com/mavenrepo" }
                maven { url "https://artifactory.domain.com/maven.atlassian.com-cache" }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
                classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.sherter.google-java-format:google-java-format-gradle-plugin:0.8”
            }
        }
        
        apply plugin: "com.github.sherter.google-java-format"
        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        apply plugin: 'idea'
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        
        apply plugin: 'findbugs'
        apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        
        group = 'com.domain.xyz.myapp'
        version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://artifactory.domain.com/mavenrepo" }
        }
        project.tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith("publish") } .each { it.dependsOn assemble }
        
        springBoot {
            classifier = 'boot'
        }
        
        publishing {
            publications {
                maven(MavenPublication) {
                    artifact ("$buildDir/libs/$project.name-$version-boot.jar") {
                        classifier = 'boot'
                    }
                }
            }
            
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url "http://artifactory.xyz.com:8080/project-snapshots"
                     credentials {
                        username = "publish-username"
                        password = "publish-password"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
            reports {
                xml.enabled false
                html.enabled true
            }
        }
        
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
        }
        
        dependencies {
            compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
            annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8')  
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
            compile('org.springframework:spring-web')
             compile('com.google.guava:guava:r05')
          runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.16')
            runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.3')
            runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
            testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
            testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
            compile('com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53')
            compile('net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1')
            compile('jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17')
            compile('org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.0')
                       compile('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1')
            compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-spring-legacy:1.5.6')
        }
```

Package Structure :

Project

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
   Application properties 
build.gradle
gradlew
```

This is a gradle build system that I am using here.I have seen some similar questions where people deleted .m2 repository and solved it.For gradle I tried following command to re-download dependencies

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

but it did not solve my problem

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your POM? Please post the POM and the package structure

Comment: it is a gradle not maven ,added build.gradle and package structure

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `HibernateJpaConfiguration`'s constructor, is it getting hit?

Comment: If you start your application with a `--debug` command line argument, it should output a condition evaluation report which will show what was and was not auto-configured. It should reveal what happened with the auto-configuration of Hibernate.

Comment: under positive matches section ,i see : HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager', 'org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor' (OnClassCondition)

Comment: any leads anyone? I tried clearing gradle cache,m2 cache, that did not help me.its working fine in 1.5.6.Release spring boot. but upgrade has issues.